# logical operation in java

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have been trying to implement the following condition in a more sofisticated manner:

```
if (x > 1) 
 doSomething();
else {
 doSomethingElse();
}
```

want to code it like:

```
(x > 1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

Is this not possible at all?

Comment: change function name in if/else also

Comment: There is nothing 'more sophisticated' about your preferred notation. It is merely your preferred notation. The execution in the JVM would be identical, if it compiled, which it doesn't, because it isn't valid Java code. Not a real question.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible if  `doSomething()` returns `void`. Refer the [JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> **It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.**
>
> In fact, by the grammar of expression statements (§14.8), it is not permitted for a conditional expression to appear in any context where an invocation of a void method could appear.

Eventually the second and third operand should evaluate to the same type, how this evaluation is done is also mentioned in the JLS.

**P.S:** Why you want to `doSomething()` for both `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 2):

You can write things like this:

```
i = (x > 1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

But not directly like this:

```
(x > 1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

Because in [JLS §14.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

> ### 14.8. Expression Statements
>
> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons.
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>     StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>     Assignment
>     PreIncrementExpression
>     PreDecrementExpression
>     PostIncrementExpression
>     PostDecrementExpression
>     MethodInvocation
>     ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```

There is no `ConditionalExpression` in it.

Comment: `i = (x > 1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();` Will this work if the 2nd and 3rd operands returns void ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yes, if he can declare `void i;` (So --> No)

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem - just changed my methods to private int doSomething(), private int doSomethingElse() and then the expression to int val = (x > 1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();

Comment: @user2365568 What? I said `i = ...` only for clarification. I suggest you to keep the originally `if-else` unless `val` is meaningful.

Comment: I have been thinking about this. val has no use and one may be more confused when reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not in full generality; the arguments in the ternary (formally the ternary requires *expressions*) have to evaluate to the same type.

If doSomething() is a `void` type then certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on return type.If you define like this `void doSomething()` then its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary is used for inline if conditions. They need a return value, because u could write something like that:

```
System.out.println((x > 1) ? "True" : "False");
```

with void this would not be possible